# AnimationView is lagging

Tags: java, android

I have implement `Animationview` to my App. When i play it it's lagging . I tried to solve this but i failed.

Here is the code:

```
        Top = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.top_animation);
        Bottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bottom_animation);

        Im = findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        tx = findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        tx2 = findViewById(R.id.textView9);

        Im.setAnimation(Top);
        tx.setAnimation(Bottom);
        tx2.setAnimation(Bottom);
```

bottom_animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromAlpha="0.1"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

top_animation :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="-50%" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromAlpha="0.1"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: can I see top_animation and bottom_animation xml source ?

Comment: Check. I have updated the question.